# mysql count number of hashtags through table

Tags: php, mysql, regex

i have mysql table text(id, text) with values:

```
1, 'some #text with #hashtags ...'
2, 'more #text without....'
... and more
```

is possible in sql get count for any hashtags ?
something

`like select count(regexp) from text where...regexp... magic happened ;)`

needed result: #text ...2x, $#hashtags 1x

i cant select text with

```
select * from  table where text REGEXP '#[a-z]*
```

but this way i get only rows with any #hashtag

Any idea ?

Ok, i can select all and count in result with php of course, but its possible only mysql solution ?

Answer (score 0):

1. **Select rows from MySQL** `SELECT text FROM text WHERE text REGEXP '#(\w+)'`

`\w` means `Any word character (letter, number, underscore)`

`+` means `one or more`

2. **Get hashtag** from `text column` **using the** [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) with the same pattern '#(\w+)' and using the $match (**take a look at the reference!**)

$match =

```
Array
(
    [0] => #hashtag
    [1] => hashtag
)
```

3. **Count in array**, `$hashtags_count[$match[1]]++`